# Double-click open .txt files in the same emacs frame (if one is currently open)

Tags: windows, emacs

I would like to set emacs as the default editor for text files when I double-click open them in Windows.
However I would like to open them asa buffer  in the same running instance of emacs (i.e. frame) , if any.
Right now the behaviour will open another instance of emacs (i.e. another emacs frame).

Does anyone know which specification in init.el would allow this behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been using [this guy's](http://robert-adesam.blogspot.com/2011/01/emacsclient-setup-on-windows-7-starter.html) approach, which is an alternative to adding entries to the registry. I've reproduced his steps here:

- Create the following batch file 'runemacsclientw.bat'.

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::
::: Emacsclient startup script runemacsclientw.bat
::: Robert Adesam, robert@adesam.se
::: http://www.adesam.se/robert/
:::
::: N.B. Alot of this is reused from other Emacs
::: users that have published stuff on the
::: Internet. Thank you! :)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
:: Emacs binaries...
set binpath=c:\Program Files\emacs\bin
:: If no arg is given set filename to c:\
if "%~1"=="" (
  set filename=c:\
) else (
  set filename=%~1
)
:: Run Emacsclient
"%binpath%\emacsclientw.exe" --no-wait --alternate-editor="%binpath%\runemacs.exe" "%filename%"
```

- Convert the bat file to exe with a [bat to exe converter](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e)

  - Choose batch file.
  - Check 'invisible application'.
  - Under 'version information' select an icon (if you want to make it purdy)
  - Compile and exit.
- Copy 'runemacsclientw.bat' to .../emacs/bin.
- Associate file types with runemacsclientw.bat.
- Add (server-start) to init file.
- Change owner of ~/.emacs.d/server (in %appdata%) to the current user (it will default to local administrator). This removes the "unsafe directory ~/.emacs.d/server" warning.

Comment: I guess you meant an `exe` file in `Associate file types with runemacsclientw.bat`, right?

Comment: @Alexey, it's been a long time since I answered this but I _think_ I meant "associate the file type you want to open with Emacs with runemacsclientw.bat". For example, ".txt", ".c", etc.

Comment: It's just more logical to associate it with an `exe`. Otherwise one would have a terminal window opened and we convert `bat` to `exe` here to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

First have a quick look at emacsclient documentation.

Then in your init.el file start the emacsclient server by running:

`(server-start)`

Next we'll add some keys to the registry which gives an "Edit with Emacs" option in the context menu for all files.

Add the following keys:

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Emacs]
@="Edit with Emacs"`

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Emacs\command]
@="c:\Program Files (x86)\emacs-23.2\bin\emacsclientw.exe" --no-wait  --alternate-editor="c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.2/bin/runemacs.exe" "%1"

The quotes are literal and should be included. You may have to play with the paths a bit so that they fit your environment.

As for the double-click behavior it's a matter of knowing which registry keys to add. If you know that they you should be able to generalize this answer to the behavior you want.

The program emacsclient will blast the file into a running copy of emacs (provided you ran 'server-start') or if there is not an existing copy it will run the command supplied with the "alternate-editor" option.

Comment: You might need to change owner of ~/.emacs.d/server (that's in %appdata%) to the current user (it will default to local administrator). This removes the "unsafe directory ~/.emacs.d/server" warning.

Comment: I have to try this registry edit since I did create a shortcut with params --no-wait --alternate-editor="c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.2/bin/runemacs.exe" "%1" with my appropriate paths and used that as the default program but I got an error saying --alternate-editor or server instance are not present which I assume means that it didn't get the arguments from my shortcut. However, when running the command line it says ~/.emacs.d/server.d/ location unsafe. ANy ideas?

Comment: ill try this method also. I just don't like messing with the registry that much. Also don't you need Admin rights to open regedit.exe?

Comment: @octi Yeah you need admin to open regedit AFAIK. As to your first comment, it does look like the arguments are not being picked up. For what it's worth the approach suggested by Ben is nice, and easier to implement.